# How to change the UI language of TOpenDialog on-the-fly in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I am writing an application in Windows 10 and Delphi 10.4.

Q1. How to change the UI language of TopenDialog as I expect, manually? (not automatically selected by Windows).

```
var
  aOpenDlg: TOpenDialog;
begin
  aOpenDlg := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);
  if LangID = 1 then { Chinese UI }
    begin
……
end
  else { English UI }
begin
……
end;
end;
```

Q2. How to make the TopenDialog as a MDIChild? So, it appears properly in MDIForm application.

Thanks.

Comment: (Q1) `TOpenDialog` is a wrapper for the native OS dialog. It is not the responsibility of an application to localise this. Don't touch it. (Q2) In a Win32 MDI app, file dialogs are still (conventionally) app-modal.

Comment: It is proper for a dialog to appear modal. What do you want to do here ?

Comment: You can't make a TOpenDialog a MDIChild, because it's not ever intended to be used as a MDIChild winodw. What sense would it make for a dialog that is shown only momentarily to be a MDIChild? None of the system dialogs support being a MDIChild, because they were never intended to be used improperly like that, so the behavior you're seeing now is absolutely normal and correct.

Comment: Thank you all.
@ GuidoG. When a OpenDialog executes, I hope that it display with the language I expect. Such as the form’s title, button’s captions.